# Why doesn't this perl regex work

Tags: regex, perl

```
@matches = ( $filestr =~ /^[0-9]+\. (.+\n)*/mg );
```

I have a file that's been read into filestr, yet for some reason the above regex, which should match the beginning of a line, followed by a number, a dot, a space, and then any number of lines followed by a newline (thus ending when there is a line with only a newline on it), seems to just produce some single lines from the file.

When I do something like

```
@matches = ( $filestr =~ /^[0-9]+\. .+\n/mg );
```

I correctly match a single line.

When I do this

```
@matches = ( $filestr =~ /^[0-9]+\. .+\n.+\n/mg );
```

I match the same single lines, followed by some seemingly unrelated line. What's wrong with my regex?

Note: The regex works fine in this regex tester:https://regex101.com/, it just won't work in perl.

Example, in this text:

```
1. This should
match

2. This should too

3. This
one
also
```

the regex should match

```
1. This should
match
```

and

```
2. This should too
```

and

```
3. This
one
also
```

Comment: Just FYI: when line breaks come into play, consider using `\R` instead of `\n`. However, here you'd better change the whole approach and read line by line checking each subsequent one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried \R but I get the same result as with \n.

Comment: Do you know of a good way to check line by line the way you suggested? It seems like I would essentially be manually splitting apart the regex. First checking if a line matched ^[0-9]+\. , then checking if a line matched .+\n for the rest of the first line and all subsequent lines (until I got a line with only a single newline on it, at which point I would have to restart).

Comment: could you post the sample lines for matching the regex

Comment: I can only suggest a regex fix like `/^[0-9]+\..*?(?:\R{2}|\z)/gsm`

Comment: I would suggest you to try this regex `/(^[0-9]+\. (?:.+\n)*)/gm`. That means keep the whole match into single result-set.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: @AruneshSingh you should make that an answer, not a comment.  That looks right to me, that the regex in the question is matching correctly but not capturing what he wants.

Comment: @WillBolden you do a good job showing what you've tried, sample input, and desired results, but next time please also show the results you actually get with your sample input

Comment: @ysth Added. Thanks.

Comment: In list context (provided by the assignment to array `@matches`) a global regular expression returns all the *captured* substrings of every match. If you want the whole matched string to be stored then you need to change your parentheses to non-capturing ones `(?: ... )`. Or if you are using a recent version of Perl then you may use the `/n` modifier which makes ordinary parentheses non-capturing, so `/^[0-9]+\. (.+\n)*/mng` will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is right. But, you are capturing the result partially. I would suggest you to capture the whole match into a single result-set and that's how it is going to be stored into `@matches`.

So, the correct regex would become `/(^[0-9]+\. (?:.+\n)*)/gm`. In this way you are capturing the matched result into `$1`. Wrapping it up into a program yields.

Although, it is going to work without keeping those parenthesis`(...)` also because by default it takes `$&`(i.e whole match) unless you capture anything. So, remember in these cases you should use [`non-capturing group(?: ... )`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings) instead of capturing group`()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = '
1. This should
match

2. This should too

3. This
one
also
';

my @matches = $str =~ /^([0-9]+\. (?:.+\n)*)/gm;

print Dumper(\@matches);
```

**Output:**

```
[
          '1. This should
match
',
          '2. This should too
',
          '3. This
one
also
'
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, instead of reading the file by line, you should read it by paragraph. To do that you need to set `$/` to the empty string. example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @result;

{
    local $/ = "";
    while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        push @result, $_ ;
        # or to filter paragraphs that don't start with a digit, use instead:
        # push @result, $_ if /^[0-9]+\./; 
    }
}


__DATA__
1. This should
match

2. This should too

3. This
one
also
```